# How perform post call using react tool kit query without endpoint and operate on body

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, rtk-query

Currently I am using rtk ( react tool kit) query to do an api call using redux , Current Url being static (ex:http://dummy.yt/fetch/) and body can be changed to get the desired result , API is an post request with a body looks like bellow

```js
{
  "type": "Data_one",
  "include": "*",
  "limit":4,
  "offset": 0
}
```

Body updates here with every call for example offset will be changed to 1 , most of the examples on documentation talk about endpoints ( giving input to the URL) but I want this data to fetched In one single call and later optimize it using rtk query by **alerting the body** the way they are doing to the endpoint.

can we achieve this using RTK query?

Answer (score 0):

You still need a query endpoint. Just one that does not return a string, but an object.

Instead of

```js
query: arg => `some/url/${arg}`
```

do

```js
query: arg => ({
  url: 'some/url',
  method: 'POST',
  body: {
    something: "foo",
    anotherThing: arg
  }
})
```